# Fix image to center of shiny page and center it

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an image that I want to be centered at the bottom of the page regardless of the page size. Using the code below, however, will fix the image to the left side of the page instead of the center. Is there a way for me to center it at the bottom?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        img(
          src ='testfig.png',
          style = 'position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 45vh; left: auto; right: auto;'
          )
        )
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with custom CSS:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .bottom-centered-img {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 45vh;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
    ")),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        img(src = 'testfig.png', class = 'bottom-centered-img')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This however removed the figure from the page entirely